# Multiple datatables size issue with JQuery/Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatable

I have a problem with two datatables in one page(dtable1 and dtable2) that i put in tab panel.

The table width of dtable2 become smaller after retrieve data by ajax.

```
<div role="tabpanel">
            <!-- Nav tabs -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#allocationtab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">ALLOCATION</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#registrationtab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">REGISTRATION</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="allocationtab">
                <br/>
                <div class="x_content">
                  <table id="allocationdatatable">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>AWB Start</th>
                      <th>AWB End</th>
                      <th>AWB Count</th>
                      <th>Created By</th>
                      <th>Created Date</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>

                  </table>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="registrationtab">
                <br/>
                <div class="x_content">
                  <table id="registrationdatatable">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>AWB Start</th>
                      <th>AWB End</th>
                      <th>AWB Count</th>
                      <th>Register By</th>
                      <th>Register Date</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>


                  </table>
                </div>

            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[tab panel dtable2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agCqm.png)

If I remove the tab panel from the script, no issue exists on both datatable.
Appreciate if any member could help.
Thanks

Comment: try setting the width to 100% for the table. its probably autoresizing for the new content. might even be a setting you can turn off - check the docs.

Comment: That's a simple solution that never thought. 
Thank @Alex, it's worked. :)

Comment: fyi if you want it to be responsive there is a responsive datatables plugin